# ASP.Net MVC HABTM Association

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, has-and-belongs-to-many

I must be missing something, when trying to define a HABTM association with 2 of my models.  I have a "Product" table, and a "Category" table, and a "ProductsCategories" join table.  In SQL Server, I am defining the Relationship between the tables on the join table.  However, when I create the LINQ to SQL model "Product," I get "Product.ProductCategories -> ProductCategory, ProductsCategory.Product -> Product"  Is it possible in asp.net mvc to define a relationship that would give me Product.Categories or Category.Products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone is surely wiser than me on the subject, but I don't know a way of doing this [automatically] if you are using a DBML file to autogenerate your database model. By knowing you can use  `Product.ProductCategories.Category` and `Category.ProductCategories.Product`, you can create partial classes for Product and Category that define properties named `Products` and `Categories` which return Product.ProductCategories.Category, and Category.ProductCategories.Product.